# Reference to end is ambiguous

Tags: c++

Can anyone explain why am I getting "reference to 'end' is ambiguous" is following code? I get this is because of a clash with std::end. But if I put the end inside the main function, it does not show the error. How is defining in global scope different than defining in main function's scope?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
int *end;

int main() {
    return end == NULL;
}
```

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:7:12: error: reference to 'end' is ambiguous
     return end == NULL;
            ^
prog.cpp:4:6: note: candidates are: int* end
 int *end;
      ^
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/stdc++.h:94:0,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/valarray:1226:5: note:                 template<class _Tp> const _Tp* std::end(const std::valarray<_Tp>&)
     end(const valarray<_Tp>& __va)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/valarray:1216:5: note:                 template<class _Tp> _Tp* std::end(std::valarray<_Tp>&)
     end(valarray<_Tp>& __va)
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:51:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/sstream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/complex:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ccomplex:38,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/stdc++.h:52,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/range_access.h:97:5: note:                 template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> constexpr _Tp* std::end(_Tp (&)[_Nm])
     end(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/range_access.h:78:5: note:                 template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(const _Container&)
     end(const _Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.end())
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/range_access.h:68:5: note:                 template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(_Container&)
     end(_Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.end())
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/range_access.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/string:51,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/sstream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/complex:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ccomplex:38,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/stdc++.h:52,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/initializer_list:99:5: note:                 template<class _Tp> constexpr const _Tp* std::end(std::initializer_list<_Tp>)
     end(initializer_list<_Tp> __ils) noexcept
     ^
```

Comment: Because of [`std::end`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiler can't differentiate between your (globals) `int* end` and [std::end](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) after you introduced the entire `std` namespace into the current (global) scope using the `using namespace std;`. [Avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) using `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Why does it not cause an error when I move the declaration inside the function's scope?

Comment: @atuly Because of local [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope).